# How to find the nth occurrence of an element if the elements are not on the same level using webdriver and css?

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

The page I'm trying to automate has n same buttons at different levels. These n buttons have same attributes. Lets say, if I want to click on the second, how could I do that using webdriver and CSS, thanks.

Comment: do you mean, for example, you have 2 separate list items and you want to select the second button of both lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

say for example that unique attribute is class='custom_button' you can use

```
List <WebElement> custButtons = driver.findElements(By.className("custom_button"));
custButtons.get(2).click();
```

this will click on the third button with classname 'custom_button' on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Prashant Shukla has the right answer.

---

Anyway, if you wanted to do it on a single line with a single command:

I am not aware of a way how to do it with a single CSS selector (even pseudo selectors like `:nth-child()` don't allow it). But somebody may know the answer. What I can propose is an XPath selector. The trick is to use the `descendant` axis.

For example, if you wanted to select the second `<a class='post-tag'>` element on the page (which happens to be the `webdriver` tag on this page :) ) regardless of anything else, you'd do:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/descendant::a[@class='post-tag'][2]"));
```